# C# Кодирование строки посимвольно

Tags: c#, массивы, кодировка, ascii

я не знаю, как каждый символ строки в цикле перекодировать в номер ASCII элемента. Имеется str - строка english\russian букв.

Это работает

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(str);
```

А это нет - пишет,подчёркивает `str[i]` мол не удаётся char в char[] преобразовать.
Может это из-за того, что в первом случае массив, а тут нет.

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(str[i])
```

Мне бы представление номера в int, чтобы через него вычислять позицию символа в алфавите

Comment: `str[i]` — не строка, а символ

Comment: А вообще, в ASCII нет русских букв, так что ваше задание так, как оно сформулировано, невыполнимо.

Comment: ASCII и 1251 это не одно и то же

Comment: Я не очень в этом разбираюсь, почему  `byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(str);
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(bytes[i]);`  выдаёт коды для русских символов?

Comment: Да, str[i] символ, а для символа не работает?

Comment: А если написать все так же, только `str[i]` заменить на `str[i].ToString()`

Comment: Не помогло, терь в int нельзя преобразовать

Comment: А разве не работает int num = (int)'c';

Comment: А что нельзя преобразовать? Там по идее на выходе массив байтов должен быть. Так что преобразуйте только 0-й элемент

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Windows-1251](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) - однобайтовая кодировка. Следовательно, в итоговом массиве каждый байт будет сооветствовать одному символу строки с тем же индексом. Поэтому можно сперва всю строку перевести в массив байт в этой кодировке, а потом итерироваться по массиву, получая коды символов.

```
var str = "Привет";

byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(str);

for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(str[i] + " - " + bytes[i]);
```

Answer (score -1):

На вход методу `GetBytes` нужно подавать строку или массив символов, но не один символ типа `char`. Поэтому следует преобразовывать символ в строку методом `ToString`.

Получившийся массив будет всегда иметь длину 1. Это и есть код символа.

```
var str = "Привет";

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(str[i].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(str[i] + " - " + bytes[0]);
}
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, а что такое 'c'

Comment: Символ любой char , в данном случае c

Comment: Надеюсь не будете возражать против моей правки.

Comment: зачем вытаскивать символ из строки, превращать его в строку и после этого кодировать, если может просто всю строку перекодировать заранее?

Comment: @tym32167 - вопрос изначально поставлен топикстартером именно так. Ответ формально правильный.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я не говорю, что ответ неправильный, я говорю, что код неэффективный